# Process an element both through a generic and a targeted template

Tags: templates, xslt-1.0

I'm new at XSL and still not sure of some of my terminology. I'm currently facing something I can't seem to crack. I'm attempting to

1. Search through all data nodes (leaf elements?) of input XML and replace text
2. Search through all attribute values in input XML and replace text
3. Copy over other nodes to output
4. Copy over processor instructions and comments to output
5. Match and process specific nodes in the input

The issues I'm facing are:

A. Not sure of the terminology (see the comments in files below) and the tack I'm taking in attacking this

B. The template (5) above, whenever it matches a node, seems to be preventing the other templates (1 and 2) from processing it

If it makes a difference, I'm running this on Windows, using Microsoft's processor and am using XSLT 1.0. I've included simplified versions of the input (Input.xml), XSLT (Transform.xslt) and the output (Output.xml) I'm getting.

I did try using "mode" to run the targeted template (5) from the generic search and replace templates (1 and 2) but, in that case, template 1 and 2 run but the targeted template (5) itself doesn't run.

I'd appreciate any comments and suggestions.

### Input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List>
    <Item Name="Item1" Text="abcd"/>
    <Item Name="Itembc" Text="qrst"/>
    <Item Name="Special" Text="Hello, Worldbc"/>
    <Item Name="Special" Text=""/>
</List>
```

### Transform.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:myjs="urn:custom-javascript" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl myjs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="myjs">
    <![CDATA[
        function EscapeRegExp(str)
        {
            return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
        }

        function StringReplace(strWhere, strWhat, strBy, strFlags)
        {
            return strWhere.replace ( new RegExp(EscapeRegExp(strWhat), strFlags), strBy);
        }

    ]]>
    </msxsl:script>

    <!-- ********************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!--                                                                                                                        -->
    <!-- Because of the following 4 templates, the identity transform is not needed in this XSLT                                -->
    <!--                                                                                                                        -->
    <!-- ********************************************************************************************************************** -->

    <!-- 1 of 4: Copy all nodes from source XML to the final XML, searching and replacing -->
    <!--         Modify (1 of 4) and (2 of 4) to support additional replacement           -->
    <!-- Search and Replace in attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:variable name="TempAttrValue" select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="myjs:StringReplace(string($TempAttrValue), 'bc', '2', 'g')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <!-- xsl:apply-templates mode="TargetedTemplate"/ -->
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- 2 of 4: Copy all nodes from source XML to the final XML, searching and replacing -->
    <!--         Modify (1 of 4) and (2 of 4) to support additional replacement           -->
    <!-- Search and Replace in data nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:variable name="TempTextValue" select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="myjs:StringReplace(string($TempTextValue), 'bc', '3', 'g')"/>
        <!-- xsl:apply-templates mode="TargetedTemplate"/ -->
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- 3 of 4: Copy all nodes from source XML to the final XML, searching and replacing -->
    <!-- Process element nodes but not attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- 4 of 4: Copy all nodes from source XML to the final XML, searching and replacing -->
    <!-- Leave the comment nodes and processing instruction nodes alone -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- 5 : Process specific nodes -->
    <!-- Assumes an item in the input called Special and fills it with (No Data) if it is empty -->
    <!-- Seems to be interfering with 1-4 above. Changing the [@Name='Special'] to [@Name='SpecialA'] will let 1-4 above to work -->
    <xsl:template match="Item[@Name='Special']/@Text">
        <xsl:attribute name="Text">
            <xsl:variable name="TempSpecialText" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="($TempSpecialText = '')">(No Data)</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$TempSpecialText"/></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List>
    <Item Name="Item1" Text="a2d">
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Item2" Text="qrst">
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Special" Text="Hello, Worldbc">
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Special" Text="(No Data)">
    </Item>
</List>
```

### Output - Desired.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List>
    <Item Name="Item1" Text="a2d">
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Item2" Text="qrst">
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Special" Text="Hello, World2">
    </Item>
    <Item Name="Special" Text="(No Data)">
    </Item>
</List>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Requirements 1 and 2 are ill-defined - Replace with what? What are your rules of transformation? Requirement 4 is entailed in 3. Requirement 5 is pointlessly vague. Issue A is too vague - what terms do you want defined? Issue B - you need to specify the desired output. You've given one test case, which is good, but it is so trivial, I suspect that it does not serve to illustrate all the issues you are trying to deal with. Add some more test cases.

Comment: To Sean:

I want to do some string replacements. Since the details are not pertinent to the issue I'm having, I included the simplest possible examples that show the main issue I need help with.

For each of the requirements I mentioned, I included the number of the requirement in the comment above the corresponding template in the XLST I included in my question. 

The desired output is included above! Don't you see the Output-Desired.xml?

Comment: I'll come back to this on Monday, if no one else answers. Are you stuck with XSLT 1? Can you use XSLT 2 or 3 (eg Saxon engine)?

Comment: If I could use XSLT 2.0 I'd have tried <xsl:next-match/>. Did you downrate the question that somebody had uprated earlier?

Comment: I did not downrate any thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is with your final template

```
<xsl:template match="Item[@Name='Special']/@Text">
    <xsl:attribute name="Text">
        <xsl:variable name="TempSpecialText" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($TempSpecialText = '')">(No Data)</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$TempSpecialText"/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will match your `<Item Name="Special" Text="Hello, Worldbc">` element ahead of the template that just matches `@*`. However, the `Text` attribute is not empty, and your `xsl:otherwise` simply outputs the value again, and doesn't do the replace you want. The `<xsl:apply-templates/>` here is unnecessary because attributes do not have any child nodes to select.

What you can do is this...

```
<xsl:template match="Item[@Name='Special']/@Text">
    <xsl:attribute name="Text">
        <xsl:variable name="TempSpecialText" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($TempSpecialText = '')">(No Data)</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="myjs:StringReplace(string($TempSpecialText), 'bc', '2', 'g')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

But this is duplication of code. A better solution would be to change the template only match empty attributes, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="Item[@Name='Special']/@Text[. = '']">
    <xsl:attribute name="Text">(No Data)</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

That way it will only match the `<Item Name="Special" Text=""/>` element, where as the `<Item Name="Special" Text="Hello, Worldbc"/>` will be matched by the generic `@*` template.

Be wary of using Microsoft specific extension functions, as this obviously limits you to running on Microsoft platforms. If you limited to XSLT 1.0, this means using a recursive template. (See [Find and replace entity in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503644/find-and-replace-entity-in-xslt) as an example). Alternatively, if you can switch to XSLT 2.0, the `replace` function comes as standard.

Comment: This is part of a much larger initiative where the tools and technologies were established before the development began. I have to use DotNet and compatible tools; also means XSLT 1,0. Thanks for the suggestions and the code. Unfortunately, as a newcomer, I can't uprate any answers yet

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:myjs="urn:custom-javascript" 
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl myjs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="myjs">
<![CDATA[
    function EscapeRegExp(str)
    {
        return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    }

    function StringReplace(strWhere, strWhat, strBy, strFlags)
    {
        return strWhere.replace ( new RegExp(EscapeRegExp(strWhat), strFlags), strBy);
    }

]]>
</msxsl:script>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[contains(., 'bc')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="myjs:StringReplace(string(.), 'bc', '2', 'g')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[not(string())]">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:text>(No Data)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```